# CSS best practice - align with first :

Tags: css

Is it best practice (or looked down upon) when coding in CSS to align properties based on colons (':')? I recently came across a few plugins for Sublime Text that will align your code. I assumed it would make it more readable, but am wondering which style is generally more preferred.

Example (aligned):

```
a:link {
    color          : #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or do professional developers generally prefer them not aligned (like so):

```
a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neither has a significant impact on developer performance except to waste time in argument.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about aligning. It doesn't really help for readability and it will later get messed up when someone in the future (including you) doesn't take the time nor has the time to keep with that format.